# How to run ClassCleanup (MSTest) after each class with test?

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

I have several classes with tests suites.

Each test class starts from ClassInitialize and finishes by ClassCleanup.
My problem is that ClassCleanup isn't called at the end of each class, it's called only after all tests in three classes.
Can I fix this issue? Thanks!

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void SetUpBrowser(TestContext context)
{
    pageObjectBase.SetBrowser("chrome");
    pagesManager.GetPageObjectBase();
}

[TestMethod]
public void FindCriticalBug()
{
    bla-bla-bla();
}

[ClassCleanup]
public static void CloseBrowser()
{
    pageObjectBase.Stop();
    pagesManager.GeneralClearing();
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Tests are run unordered, including tests across classes.  See this blog post:

https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ploeh/classcleanup-may-run-later-than-you-think

To quote:

> In any case, here's the result from my Output Window:
>
> ```
> AssemblyInitialize
> TestClass1: ClassInitialize
> TestClass1: TestInitialize
> TestClass1: MyTestCase1
> TestClass1: TestCleanup
> TestClass2: ClassInitialize
> TestClass2: TestInitialize
> TestClass2: MyTestCase2
> TestClass2: TestCleanup
> TestClass1: ClassCleanup
> TestClass2: ClassCleanup
> AssemblyCleanup
> ```
>
> ...this doesn't mean that TestClass1's ClassCleanup executes immediately after the last test case in the class! In fact, it waits until all test cases are executed, and the executes
> together with TestClass2's ClassCleanup.
>
> This surprised me at first, but that was obviously only because I
> hadn't really thought it through: Since tests are, in principle,
> unordered, there's not guarantee that all tests in TestClass1 are
> executed in immediate succession. Theoretically, the execution engine
> may pick a test case from TestClass1, then one from TestClass2, then
> another from TestClass1, etc. Since that is the case, there's no
> guarantee that all tests from one test class have been executed before
> a new test class is initialized, and thusly, all ClassCleanup methods
> may as well be deferred until all test cases have been executed.

Unfortunately, you'll have to look at ordered tests or at a different unit testing framework if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: I didn't realize that TestClass1's ClassCleanup doesn't execute until all test cases are executed. I think this may be why I'm only seeing an error in TestClass2 if I run it with TestClass1, but not if I run it alone. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

There is a different attribute called [TestCleanupAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute.aspx), which will run after every test.

There is also an attribute to run before every test called [TestInitializeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx).

Here is an example of them running together.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
   [ClassInitialize]
   public void ClassInitialize() { Debug.Print("Running ClassInitialize"); }

   [TestInitialize]
   public void TestInitialize() { Debug.Print("Running    TestInitialize"); }

   [TestMethod]
   public void TestMethod1() { Debug.Print("Running       TestMethod1....."); }

   [TestMethod]
   public void TestMethod2() { Debug.Print("Running       TestMethod2....."); }

   [TestCleanup]
   public void TestCleanup() { Debug.Print("Running    TestCleanup"); }

   [ClassCleanup]
   public void ClassCleanup() { Debug.Print("Running ClassCleanup"); }
}
```

This will result in

```
Running ClassInitialize
Running    TestInitialize
Running       TestMethod1.....
Running    TestCleanup
Running    TestInitialize
Running       TestMethod2.....
Running    TestCleanup
Running ClassCleanup
```

Comment: Note `TestMethod1` and `TestMethod2` may be run out of order.

Comment: I don't need to use TestCleanup. I need to call ClassCleanup after all tests in one class. Example: Class1 -> ClassInitialize -> Test1 -> Test2 -> Test3 -> ClassCleanup -> Class2 -> ClassInitialize -> Test4 -> Test5 -> Test6 -> ClassCleanup -> Class3...

Comment: It looks like the framework doesn't support it out of the box. You'd have to track all of the tests individually, then in the `TestCleanup`, perform the check and cleanup when they have all run.

Comment: Imo, the methods decorated with [ClassCleanup/Initialize] should be marked static.  Because the framework actually creates a new class instance for each test method.  The static doesn't change the actual operation but it avoids someone thinking that cleanup and initialize are occurring within the same instance (only true if there is just 1 test).  It seems strange because the naming doesn't match what's actually happening.

Answer (score 4):

I made a few tests and using a static field in the class to "tell" the TestCleanup method that all methods have run seems to work. You can then drop the ClassCleanup and do something like this:

```
private static int runs = 0;

[ClassInitialize]
public static void SetUpBrowser(TestContext context)
{
    pageObjectBase.SetBrowser("chrome");
    pagesManager.GetPageObjectBase();
}

[TestMethod]
public void FindCriticalBug()
{
    runs++;
    bla-bla-bla();
}

[TestMethod]
public void FindCriticalBug2()
{
    runs++;
    ble-ble-ble();
}

[TestCleanup]
public static void CloseBrowser()
{
    if (runs == 2)
    {
        pageObjectBase.Stop();
        pagesManager.GeneralClearing();
    }
}
```

I'd stay *very* far away from this solution though, but if you have no other alternative, and you can't refactor your design to use the provided lifecycle, it might be an option. You could probably get fancier here and write your own base class that counts executions and gets the total amount of test methods using reflection to automate this stuff.

Comment: You could simplify your code a bit by moving `runs++` to a `[TestInitialize]` method. Then if you decrement `runs` in `[TestCleanup]` and check to see if it's `0` it will support running a subset of the tests.

Comment: @Grinn that will actually result in the clean logic to take place right after the first test finishes

Comment: @MarkSegal That's a fair point. Perhaps I was running `async` tests when I wrote this? ¯\(°_o)/¯

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ClassCleanupBehavior` to decide when the clean up is done:
[MSTest v2: Test lifecycle attributes](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-test-lifecycle-attributes.htm)

> You can also customize when the cleanup method is called.    By default the
> cleanup method is called after all tests of the assembly are executed.
> You can call is earlier by using the `ClassCleanupBehavior`
> enumeration.
>
> `ClassCleanupBehavior.EndOfAssembly`: Called after all tests of the
> assembly are executed    `ClassCleanupBehavior.EndOfClass`: Called
> after all tests of the class are executed    You can customize the
> global behavior by using the assembly attribute
> `ClassCleanupExecution`.
>
> ```
> ClassCleanupExecution(ClassCleanupBehavior.EndOfClass)]
>
> [TestClass]
> public class TestClass1
> {
>     [ClassCleanup(ClassCleanupBehavior.EndOfAssembly)]
>     public static void ClassCleanup()
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("ClassCleanup");
>     }
>
>     [TestMethod]
>     public void Test1()
>     {
>     } 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Normal unittest are 'unordered', which means they can run in any order. You are probably looking for something like ordered test (see your comment on dominic). Ordered test is a special unittest project. When running ordered tests the test will run how you configure them, and teardown testclasses when they are finished. If unit test have to run in order, it is a smell that the test are interfering with each other. Interfering test are unreliable because they fail because a earlier test left some bad data or the test it self fails. You have no way a knowing what is really wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you for idea about test ordering! In my case I need just to restart browser after each class with autotests, there isn't dependency in test order.